# Could my courgettes have mosaic virus?

Tags: diagnosis

This was my first time (attempting) to grow courgettes. I used Cucurbita pepo Black Beauty seeds and all seemed ok to start with. I possibly planted them out too early (mid April) as had some unexpected cold spells but I kept them covered at night.

There was very limited growth from then on, although they’ve been in full sun and received diluted nettle tea and some tomato fertiliser over the past few weeks. Leaves on one plant we’re noticeably small, started to curl upwards and turn mottled brown/dead.

Then I noticed it on other plants, which have all stayed small with small leaves that start ok but then cup upwards. About two weeks ago they all suddenly produced flowers but nothing came of them, they just fall off.

I cut off most of the affected leaves however I’ve since noticed new twisted deformed leaves on the worst plant, and a fair few aphids present.

I’ve scoured the internet for clues and am fearing it might be a type of mosaic virus. I don’t want to leave them in any longer if that’s the case, although I don’t want to remove them if I’ve got it wrong!

If anyone could share their thoughts that would be very much appreciated.

Thank you.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: over a year later I am now studying RHS Level 2 and through my research now suspect my plants had root scorch from over fertilising (not mosaic virus).

This website provides additional information, and this paragraph fitted with my symptoms:

'Leaves first show a burning or scorching around margins, usually with older leaves being affected first. The marginal scorch progresses inward until the entire leaf withers and drops. '

https://plantdiseasehandbook.tamu.edu/landscaping/trees/ash/withering-and-scorching-of-foliage/